# How do you know which members are captured in a lambda with automatic capture?

Tags: c++, lambda

When we write [=] or [&] in a lambda capture I'm just wondering how we can be sure exactly what it captures:

```
struct Bar
{
    int memb;
    int memb2;
    int memb3;
};

std::function<void()> funcPtr;

void someFunc()
{
    Bar bar;
    Bar* barPtr = &bar;
        
    funcPtr = [=]()
    {
        std::cout << barPtr->memb;
        std::cout << barPtr->memb2;
        std::cout << barPtr->memb3;
    };
}


int main()
{
    
    funcPtr();
    
}
```

Does the lambda capture three variables or just what is at the top, the pointer? If you specify the pointer in the lambda capture, use it, and then use its members does the lambda capture the members additionally?

```
void someFunc()
{
   
    Bar* barPtr = new Bar;
       
    funcPtr = [lambdaptr = barPtr]()
    { // lambdaptr is captured, what about the three members?
        std::cout << lambdaptr;
        std::cout << lambdaptr->memb;
        std::cout << lambdaptr->memb2;
        std::cout << lambdaptr->memb3;
    };
}
```

Comment: it captures local variables by reference or copying their values.: the Bar object and/or a pointer to that object.: You are then just accessing the members like any other object. It isn't clear to me what you are confused about.

Comment: See [Lambda expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) for details about how capturing works.

Comment: @doug What I'm confused about is whether it captures the ptr or each member, if I use ptr->ptr2->ptr3->member; and ptr->ptr2->ptr3->member2; does it capture two members (member1 and member 2), or just the topmost, "ptr", and then just dereferences that to get the members. I was worried in case the object went out of scope.

Comment: This: "just the topmost, "ptr", and then just dereferences that to get the members." When you capture `bar` via =, the values can be accessed like this `bar.memb`  When you capture the pointer and access like `barPtr->memb` you are still accessing the original object, not the copy since you have only copied the pointer. So you have a dangling pointer if `bar` goes out of scope. But the `bar.memb` in the lambda still works fine since that `bar` is a copy.

Comment: If I capture automatically and use barPtr->member; in the lambda you say it captures barPtr, and dereferences it, so using barPtr->member1; barPtr->member2;; barPtr->member3; just captures one pointer? So if I want a copy of member2 using barPtr->member2 in the lambda won't give me a copy? Just a copy of the pointer?

Comment: Right. In the last example you are capturing only the pointer. It points to the `Bar` object created from the new statement.You access elements in the object, which is in the heap, just as you would anywhere else.

Comment: @doug So if I was worried about ptr in ptr->memb1 going out of scope, and I wanted to capture a copy of memb1, what would I do? Would I have to explicitly capture it in the capture list? What if I use many members of ptr and I'm worried about ptr going out of scope? Does each member of pointer have to be captured explicitly in the list?

Comment: `[memb1 = ptr->memb1]` To capture `memb1`. `[bar = *ptr]` to capture the whole object. Try https://cppinsights.io to see the function object generated from the lambda.

Comment: " What if I use many members of ptr and I'm worried about ptr going out of scope?"  The ptrs in both examples are copied so you don't care if they go out of scope. However, the `obj` in the first example could go out of scope and the copied ptr would not be valid. But the first example also copies `obj` so you can access members using the normal mechanism: `obj.memb1` even if the original `obj` is no longer there.  See the comment by @krisz  Here's a discussion of how function objects are similar to lambdas.  https://web.mst.edu/~nmjxv3/articles/lambdas.html